# jQuery slidebar for searchbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, searchbar

I'm currently working on a search box for my site that will hopefully use a slide-bar instead of tabs to conduct the search. Users will enter a search query and instead of choosing from the conventional tabs above the box, they will have the option to search based on the position of the slider (ie. a "stronger" or "weaker" range of search). Does that make sense?

Anyway, has anyone come across a plugin to help me build such a slide? jQuery? Ajax? CSS? Not sure how to go about it. Has anyone any experience or ideas with what I'm trying to achieve?

Let me know what you think, and if you need me to elaborate on anything :)

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has a [Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) control that you could use for this.

You can see from the demo's on the page that there are numerous different ways that you can use this, look at the "Snap to Increments" demo.  You could use this method and snap it to "weak", "strong", "very strong" etc?

Comment: Very nice! Thanks very much. Can't believe I bypassed this on their site. Exactly what I was looking for :)